# ScheduledExecutorService doesn't run in service at android

Tags: android

I want to run my method every 60 second at ScheduledExecutorService thread in Service, My service is running but it doesn't enter my method in ScheduledExecutorService block after 60 second, is it should be Background Limit in android? Thanks for your helps

```
 public class ScheduleChecker extends Service {

    private boolean activeSchedule;
    private Context context;
    private static SICPScocket sicpScocket;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {

            String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                    "PixageOne",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);

            channel.setSound(null, null);

            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setContentText("").build();

            startForeground(1, notification);
        }

        if (Utils.getModel().equals("10BDL4151T")) {
            if (sicpScocket == null) {
                sicpScocket = new SICPScocket(context);
                sicpScocket.socketInit();
            }
        }

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            //Get Data from Schedule File
            String getScheduleData = CommonUseFunc.readScheduleFile(context);
            Timber.tag("Schedule").e(getScheduleData);
            if (!getScheduleData.equals("")) {
                checkSchedule(getScheduleData);
            }
        }, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //runs every 60 second
    }
}
```

Manifest File

```
<service
    android:name=".network.service.ScheduleChecker"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

Comment: I tested your code, it works. do you declare service in Manifest?

Comment: Thnks for your helping,I shared define of Service in Manifest file at above

Comment: remove the codes are related to sicpScocket and CommonUseFunc.readScheduleFile and test it again. maybe some of them cause thread is blocked